# yii2 cron giving error of "PDO not found"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cron, yii2

I am running application well in yii2. I created a command controller **/commands/TestController**

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use app\models\UserProfile;
use yii\console\Controller;
use app\controllers\AppController;
/**
 * Test controller
 */
class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "cron service running";
    }

    public function actionSendBirthdaySms()
    {
        $userProfile = UserProfile::find()
            ->where('MONTH(dob) = MONTH(DATE(NOW()))')
            ->andWhere('DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW()) ')
            ->with('user')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

        foreach($userProfile as $item){
            $birthdayMessage = "Happy Birthday " . $item['user']['username'];
            //to send sms
            $this->_send_cron_sms($item['mobile'], $birthdayMessage);
        }
    }
```

I have two functions here. When I call `php /home/user/public_html/yii test/index` it gives the correct output with command line and cron both.

But when I am running `php /home/user/public_html/yii test/send-birthday-sms`, it runs OK with command line in ssh environment and I am receiving the SMS. But giving error in cron. Here is what I received in email:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
Content-type: text/html

PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'PDO' not found'

in /home/user/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:609

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

I also tried query builder but it also did not helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding these two extensions in php.ini file

```
extension=pdo.dll
extension=pdo_mysql.dll
```

I already asked the same question in [Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63896-pdo-error-in-yii2-cron-job/)